# Google Voice and reading unread sms messages

Tags: php, sms, voice

Im using a php wrapper to find all unread sms messages from my google voice phone number. The problem Im seeing though is if I send a text message to my google voice I can see the new text message I sent using the php wrapper. Then if I refresh the script its blank, this is because the php wrapper allows me to mark that text message as read. But if I send another text message from the same phone number then run the php wrapper script to check for the latest unread sms messages it now shows me 2 messages, the first message I sent and the last message I sent. It appears Google Voice just appends the second message to the first message I sent, is there a way to break that up so that I only see the latest unread message from each text message received? I rely on the message being sent to determine what to send back and if all the messages show up because the latest message was marked as unread they will get back a reply times how many times they texted my google voice number. Hope this makes sense. Perhaps there is a way to instead of marking it unread it just deletes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears Google Voice has the ability to delete a sms message by the msg id. That will just have to work for now. If anyone has a better answer please let me know!

Comment: How did you code a php wrapper to read from your google voice? I also, would like to write a script that will read message that are sent to my google voice. Can you help point me in the right direction?